# How to change URL for web app?

Tags: deployment, url, jboss

When I deploy myWebApp.war in JBoss I can access this web application by next URL:
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp

But I want to have next URL:
http://localhost:8080/support/myWebApp

What shopuld I do in order to have such URL?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to configure the context-root?

WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/support/myWebApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you deploy to http://localhost:8080/support/ ?

Comment: I tried to deploy my war into jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\web\deploy\support directory:
jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\web\deploy\support\myWebApp
But it does not help.